# How can I overwrite my array on window resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I have multiple div's with different content and same class

```
<div class="my-div"> ... some content here ... </div>
<div class="my-div"> ... some content here ... </div>
<div class="my-div"> ... some content here ... </div>
<div class="my-div"> ... some content here ... </div>
<div class="my-div"> ... some content here ... </div>
```

Now I push each individual height into an array

```
var myArray = new Array();

function pushToArray(height) {
    myArray.push(height);
}

function getHeight() {
    $('.my-div').each(function () {
        pushToArray($(this).height());
    });
}
```

This returns each individual height at document loaded. If I know call this function chain on window re-size, it will extend my array. What I want is that it replaces the existing values with the new heights.

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset the array in `getHeight` function.

```
var myArray = [];

function pushToArray(height) {
    myArray.push(height);
}

function getHeight() {
    // Reinitialize the array
    myArray = [];

    $('.my-div').each(function () {
        pushToArray($(this).height());
    });
}

// Call getHeight on window resize
$(window).resize(getHeight);
```

Comment: Oh my god, I could have get it on my own -.- Thanks, works like a charm

Comment: @SlimMarten Welcome. Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map()` to create array and use in combination with `resize` event:

```
var array;
$(window).resize(function(){
    array = $('.my-div').map(function(){
        return $(this).height();
    }).get();
}).resize();
```